# Disable the AppBarLayout background color

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to change the `AppBarLayout` background color to make it in Google style. I cannot change the elevation, because when I do it, whole view gones. Here is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/xxx">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_toolbar"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try: ```android:background="@android:color/transparent"```

Comment: I tried, the same effect

Comment: Can you describe what you get, and what you are expecting to get?

Comment: I forget about screen, sorry

Comment: Add the whole xml that contains this appbar.

Comment: Looks fine to me. 

Comment: what's the style named xxx?

Comment: I deleted it, it was random try with style. Doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the trick solution. I added to `AppBarLayout`

```
app:elevation="0dp"
android:translationZ="0.1dp"
```